# serving pictures from database using nodejs

Tags: database, node.js, file-upload

I am working on a web app and I want to serve users some of their own pictures that I will have stored in a database. I have a profile page view were I have some jade template. I want to load the users pictures when they click on their profile but I do not know where to start with that (I am relatively new to node). I have tried using google but no useful answers have come up. How can I load the user specific pictures from a database using nodeJS?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are the pictures saved in the db? If so, can you show the code that saves them? If not, how are you saving them?

Answer (score 0):

Never store image into db. It's wrong. Store path, url or other, but not Image Binary. 
Retrieve url that you have stored into db and put them into your final html.

M.